# Software/service to MANUALLY convert technical PDFs into EPUB/Kindle format?

Tags: pdf, math, document-converter, epub

I'm interested in knowing what the available options are in the market for converting highly technical articles in PDF format (with lots of math formulas) into EPUB/Kindle formats manually?

Is there good software that allows for this? Are there services that are partially human integrated that can do this for you?

The end goal would be to be able to read the articles in a Kindle or iPhone EPUB reader.

The operating system is Linux (preferred) or Windows. It doesn't matter if the service costs money or not.

Comment: I don't think that would be possible without typing the equations again in MathML. The alternative would be rendering them as images which will diminish their quality cause problems with scaling, especially for inline equations

Answer (score 3):

## My recommendation: [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/download)

- Multi-platform
- Free
- Can be automated through command line
- There's this easy-to-follow guide on how to use it on [How-to Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/19217/convert-a-pdf-ebook-to-epub-format/).

### Tests with Math objects

This is with a relatively easy equation as a PDF:

[image]

This is after the conversion to epub:

[image]

[image]

Not bad. As you can see, regular text is converted very nicely, and there are some differences between the two, but they are still recognizable. How about something a bit more difficult:

[image]

epub:

[image]

[image]